# Equivalent of Enum for Strings

Tags: c++, c, string, enums

I studied enums which expects only integer inputs and returns corresponding value to it.I want to achieve same thing but I only have strings as a input. I want to make following work -

```
enum Types {
"Absolute", //"abs"
"PURE", //"PRE"
"MIXED" //"MXD"
}
```

and probable statment could be -

```
string sTpes = Types("abs"); //this should return "Absolute"
```

or

```
string sTpes = Types("MXD"); //this should return "MIXED"
```

If not using enums, please suggest me possible ways to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? It looks like C++ to me.

Comment: @David: Now that you say it, it has even more reminiscence with C#: `string` is directly available, lack of ';' behind enum.

Answer (score 5):

There are no "string-enums", but to map from one value to another, you can use `std::map`, which is a standard template shipped with C++ platforms:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using std::map;  using std::string;

    map<string, string> ss;
    ss["abs"] = "Absolute";

    const string foo = ss["abs"];
    std::cout << ss["abs"] << ", or " << foo << std::endl;
}
```

In C++0x, if you want "safe" access that throws an exception if the key-type wasn't found, use `map::at` (actually, afair, the lack of `map::at` was just an oversight in the current standard):

```
    std::cout << ss.at("weird keY");
```

or check if it exists:

```
    if (ss.find("weird keY")==ss.end())
        std::cout << "key not found\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about c++/cli you could use this
     Hashtable^ openWith = gcnew Hashtable();

```
    // Add some elements to the hash table. There are no
    // duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
    openWith->Add("txt", "notepad.exe");
    openWith->Add("bmp", "paint.exe");
    openWith->Add("dib", "paint.exe");
    openWith->Add("rtf", "wordpad.exe");
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx#Y4406
else use map from stdlib.

I think you can also use CMAP from MFC, there is a good article about it here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/cmap_howto.aspx

Comment: Downvoter: Elaborate or stop being a pimpled troll. +1 for compensation.

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` has an integral value. Personally I simply suggest two conversion functions:

- `enum -> string`
- `string -> enum`

The first can be implemented with a simple array, the second require a binary search in a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a string array (of size 2) from string.h i think (either that or just string; one is for C and other is for cpp). first string is "abs" second is "absolute".

for example:

```
#include <string>

...

string abs[2]; //or a better name that's more relevant to you

abs[0] = "abs";
abs[1] = "absolute";

...

//pass it into the function
cout << abs[1] << endl;

...
```

Comment: i mentioned there is 2 of them: string.h and string. i couldnt remember which one was which though

Comment: but how would `std::string foo[2]` help in enabling the syntax `Enum("Value")`? I think you've basically wrote down just your very first thoughts on the problems.

Comment: it would replace the enum. if you have the 2 strings stored in it then when its passed in just return it back or print whatever value you want. cout << myArr[1]; // string arr - output = absolute

Comment: and you can make string arrays

Comment: But the OP wants a syntax like `Enum("Value")`, the OP doesn't want to hardcode array indices.

Comment: he said "If not using enums, please suggest me possible ways to achieve this." this was another possible way. the name of the array can help. fine an enum would be better if it could use strings, i was simply offering a different possible option.

Comment: Hmm okay. Maybe you should post an example to disambiguate.